# Oracle procedure or job to copy automatically data from one schema to another based on timeline

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have a table in my schema (`Schema1`) in my DB which has 8.5 mio records in a table. Most of the records older than 360 days.

I have a second schema (`Schema2`) with the same table structure and want to copy all records from `Schema1.table` older than **360 days** into this `Schema2.table`.

**As well, every week passed it should gather the next records in line to get copied.**

My below one doesnt seem to work as I expected it to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ARCHIVE_DATA
AS
   CURSOR Schema1_extract
   IS
      SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM Schema1.table;
BEGIN
   FOR Schema2_insert IN Schema1_extract
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO Schema2.table (column1, column2, column3)
              VALUES (column1, column2, column3);

         COMMIT;
      END;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

**EDIT**

Additional there is another action to be executed after the first above, because i want to purge the already merged data from the src table with below statement:

```
DELETE FROM src
      WHERE     table_date <= SYSDATE - 360
            AND table_id IN (SELECT table_id FROM trg.column);
```

Comment: Acccckkk! Processing RBAR, with a COMMIT after every singleton INSERT?  And you are going to "copy" the *same* rows, over and over,  every week, and append the copies to Schema2.table ? (I don't see anything here that limits the rows to be copied to "older than 360 days".) This "doesn't seem to work as I expected it to work" isn't very descriptive of the behavior you observe, nor does it appear to be a question. I'm surprised the procedure even compiles... seems like the intent is to reference `VALUES (Schema2_insert.column1, Schema2_insert.column2,`...

Comment: But I strongly *discourage* processing individual rows in a cursor loop, processing Row By Agonizing Row, when it would be much more efficient to process *sets* of rows. If not in one fell swoop (due to the immense size of the transaction), then at least reasonably sized chunks. It's not at all clear why you need a second table with a subset of rows from the first table. What problem is that intended to solve? (Seems like the proposed "solution" just creates an even bigger problem.) Was there a *question* here? Or were you just posting a status report?

Comment: Why not use a MERGE statement to insert records into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `MERGE`, You can replace the where condition to get the records which are older than 360 days based on your logic. ON condition should be the matching join columns of the two tables.

If the code is fine, perhaps you can schedule to run every week.

I also suggest using BULK COLLECT to insert records, have a look at [this](https://ksadba.wordpress.com/2008/06/16/updating-millions-of-rows-merge-vs-bulk-collect/)

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ARCHIVE_DATA
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE
    INTO Schema2.table trg
    USING (
            SELECT
                column1
              , column2
              , column3
            FROM
                Schema1.table
            WHERE
                col_date >= 360
        )
        src
    ON
        (
            trg.column1 = src.column1
        )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
        (
            column1
          , column2
          , column3
        )
        VALUES
        (
            src.column1
          , src.column2
          , src.column3
        )
    ;

    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, this is saying `PL/SQL: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges` i gave it DBA, but still showing this error. Do you might know which priv it is exactly require?

Comment: @Cyber Ideally, you should have the privilege or grant to insert records in the table of Schema2 from Schema1.

Comment: @Cyber Execute this from Schema2 `GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON table to Schema1;`

Comment: @Cyber Glad that it worked, by the way, how much time does it take to process all the rows? I have updated my answer with `BULK COLLECT` option.

Comment: any chance you can get me this statement into the proc? `DELETE FROM src
         WHERE     table_date <= SYSDATE - 360
               AND table_id IN (SELECT table_id
                                  FROM trg.column);`

Comment: @Cyber What is the logic behind the delete statement? I guess the delete statement has syntax errors.

Comment: The logic is as follows: after the merge in the previous statement, it should delete the record from the source table, so it is only present in the target table, but it should check if the record is already in the target table, than delete. So far I have it in 2 procedures, but would like to combine this in a single procedure.

Comment: @Cyber So the idea is to delete records from source table which are transferred to Schema2.table, correct me if  I am wrong.

Comment: @Cyber If that is the case, I suggest you post another question with your new procedure code.

Comment: Yes you are right, the records shall be deleted from the source table once they are transferred.

Comment: I have created a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007237/delete-records-from-source-table-after-those-has-been-transferred-via-stored-pro