# Delete records from source table after those has been transferred via stored procedure to target table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

this is my stored procedure which i got with kindly help by user75ponic generated.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ARCHIVE_DATA
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE
    INTO Schema2.table trg
    USING (
            SELECT
                column1
              , column2
              , column3
            FROM
                Schema1.table
            WHERE
                col_date >= 360
        )
        src
    ON
        (
            trg.column1 = src.column1
        )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
        (
            column1
          , column2
          , column3
        )
        VALUES
        (
            src.column1
          , src.column2
          , src.column3
        )
    ;

    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Now this stored proc is supposed to transfer records from source to target table and it is doing so.

My challenge is to include the below delete script into this stored procedure. The purpose is to delete the records from source table after they have been moved, but only if they are present in the target table.

Below is the delete script:

```
DELETE FROM src WHERE src.table_date <= SYSDATE - 360 AND src.table_id IN (SELECT table_id FROM trg.column);
```

as reference this is the original post: [original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984830/oracle-procedure-or-job-to-copy-automatically-data-from-one-schema-to-another-ba)

Comment: Which is the primary key of source and target table? Is there any date or other fields which differentiate the records of every week?

Comment: The PK is table_id in each table. And the table_date <= sysdate - 360 determine the age of the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing the insert, you can append the below DELETE statement to your procedure.

```
DELETE FROM schema1.src_table src
      WHERE src.table_id IN (SELECT trg.table_id
                               FROM schema2.trg_table trg
                              WHERE trg.table_id = src.table_id);
```

Comment: Glad that it worked. You need to have a close look at the time it needs to execute the query as there are millions of rows in the source and target tables.

Comment: The intention is to copy the source Schema and than just let it delete and run as a scheduled tasks.